# Sequelize specify the order of joins

Tags: join, sequelize.js, psql

I have a complex join, where the order of the included tables matters. Is there a way to get sequelize to order the joins properly in the sql it creates?

I have 3 tables: car, driver, skills
A car has many drivers who has many skills

I want to get a list of drivers, and include in that the info on their car, and any skills they have relating to that car.

My query in sequelize is:

```
driver.findAndCountAll({ limit: 5, include: [{
  model: car,
  required: true,
  duplicating: false,
}, {
  model: skill,
  where: { model: { $col: 'car.model' } },
  required: true,
  duplicating: false,
}]);
```

This is producing the following SQL

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT("driver"."id")) AS "count" FROM "driver" AS "driver"
INNER JOIN "skill" AS "skill" ON "driver"."id" = "skill"."driverId"
  AND "skill"."model" = "car"."model"
INNER JOIN "car" AS "car" ON "driver"."carId" = "car"."id" 
LIMIT 5;
```

This is failing because the reference to the car.model comes before the car table is joined.
If I copy and paste the SQL into psql and swap the order of the joins, the SQL executes fine.

Is there a way to get sequelize to fix the ordering.
(I tried changing the order of the includes, but no luck, it seems to be including them in reverse alphabetical order)

Comment: Did you try to place an include inside other include?

Comment: I didn't. I wouldn't have thought i'd be able to since both join to the drive model only, not to each other?
But in this case the nesting of the resulting models would create a problem as the result of the query is passed to a more generalised handler that expects the models to be nested on 1 deep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out sequelize does honour the order of includes. I had not noticed a transform in our code that was changing the order of the includes.